# Sending a recorded message using the Telephony API in Symbian

Tags: symbian, telephony

Is it possible to play a recorded audio file to the callee using the Telephony API in Symbian? If so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`CMdaAudioPlayerUtility` API to play an audio file to telephony uplink](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000391_-_Playing_audio_to_telephony_uplink_on_S60_2nd_Edition,_FP2_and_FP3).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a Qt or PyS60 wrapper for this?